# Filtering results json with query params phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, crud

I try to create a rest API that allows user to filter or create request with username and email.

The 1st URL return the full users list
http://localhost:4000/api/users

The second should fiter the data 
http://localhost:4000/api/users?email=XXX&username=YYY

I tried to solve this by using two methods :

```
  def index(conn, _params) do
    users = Res.list_users()
    render(conn, "index.json", users: users)
  end

  def search_user(username, email) do
    Repo.one(from t in User, where: t.username == username and t.email == email, select: t, limit: 1)
    render(conn, index.json, users: users)
  end
```

It returns an error while running it :

```
controllers/user_controller.ex:15: undefined function from/2
Console output is shown below.
Compiling 1 file (.ex)

== Compilation error in file lib/app_web/controllers/user_controller.ex ==
** (CompileError) lib/app_web/controllers/user_controller.ex:15: undefined function from/2
    (elixir) src/elixir_locals.erl:108: :elixir_locals."-ensure_no_undefined_local/3-lc$^0/1-0-"/2
(elixir) src/elixir_locals.erl:108: anonymous fn/3 in :elixir_locals.ensure_no_undefined_local/3
(stdlib) erl_eval.erl:680: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
(elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:229: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_workers/
```

thanks

Comment: You need to `import Ecto.Query` so you have access to the `from/2` macro. You will also want to use `t.username == ^username and t.email == ^email`. You can remove the `select: t` portion because that is automatic. You are also not assigning the `Repo.one/2` and you have no `users` variable in that scope currently.

Comment: Yes you're right ! I updated the code above but i still have an issue. Thanks for helping me for this "improvement" !=

Comment: You are using the same endpoint. You will want to change the one for `search_user` to be `/api/users/search` or something. You will want to do this in your `router.ex` file.

Comment: i'll do this even if it's not what is wanted ...

Comment: You **must not** modify the questions according to the advice you were given. The original question should stay the same for future visitors to get the context.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the endpoints the same, you can do something like the following

```
def index(conn, %{"username" => username, "email" => email}) do
  users = Repo.one(from t in User, where: t.username == ^username and t.email == ^email, select: t, limit: 1)
  render(conn, "filter.json", users: users)
end
def index(conn, _params) do
  users = Res.list_users()
  render(conn, "index.json", users: users)
end
```

This will now handle the scenario when you have a username and email parameters, and when you do not have both of them.